# Youtube videos being rendered in MVC

Tags: kentico, kentico-mvc

Using K12SP and its MVC model, I would like adding embedded YouTube videos in my views. I saw that in the CKEditor, there is a widget for doing so and it adds corresponding customized HTMl tags such as :

```
{^widget|(name)YouTubeVideo|(VideoURL)https%3a%2f%2fwww.youtube.com%2fwatch%3fv%3diwqgcxc0r5gfTzgw%26list%3dPLKeH-azh54PWS4kozV421JGVhCd5yw9Ia|(Width)425|(Height)355|(AutoPlay)False|(widget_displayname)YouTube+video^}
```

However, in my view, I now need to process theis syntax to actually embed the video as for the time being, it is just showing the raw code. How can I do this? I searched for some tutorial but didn't find any.

Is there a place where front-end code for these default widgets of the rich editor is made available?

Thank you for your help

Sylvain

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use regular embed markup? E.g.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/GkagBXZQvOI" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

HTML is the same for all the videos, you'll need to inject video URL into it.

Answer (score 0):

The inline widgets are not supported in the MVC approach. You still have the toolbar buttons in the CKEditor on the Content tab - but this is because you can also have a portal engine site in the same instance. So, this means, if you want to use the inline widgets, you will need to parse the text value when getting it from Kentico, extract the Youtube URL and basically replace the widget code with the HTML markup mentioned by Roman. It may be just easier to [hide the toolbar buttons for widgets](https://docs.kentico.com/k12sp/configuring-kentico/configuring-the-environment-for-content-editors/configuring-the-editor/personalizing-the-editor-toolbars-and-buttons) for your editors and let them just to insert the URL directly.